# Screen tearing issue on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Laptop (HP 15-AU171TX) using dual boot grub menu. The issue is I am experiencing screen tearing and everything moving too slow on the screen.

**Issue**

I believe the issue is that Ubuntu is not recognizing my Intel graphic card and due to this can not render stuff properly.

**Some Details**

Ubuntu details section is showing **Graphics Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe**

[Details Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HsBb.png)

This is most probably because in additional drivers section wrong Nvidia driver is selected, but if I update or choose any other Nvidia driver, my Ubuntu gets stuck in login loop after boot.

[Additional Drivers Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyAk5.png)

**What I have tried**

I have tried installing xorg-video-intel, but didn't work

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

I have tried installing mesa-utils, but didn't work

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

I have tried installing different versions of Nvidia drivers, but no gain. Login screen gets stuck in loop for most of them.

**One Possible Solution**

One possible solution suggested that I haven't tried is upgrade kernel to 4.9.
I am not sure it will work or not and the answer posted is neither accepted nor has much up votes.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Nvidia drivers you might be able to solve the tearing with the main intervention recommended to users of XFCE and LXDE for this problem: [switching to Compton as a screen compositor](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2144468). This has worked for me in Xubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 so far.

Answer (score 0):

I searched your laptop model on google (HP 15-AU171TX) and it appears to have hybrid graphics. This could be a good news or bad news, depending on how HP installed the geforce 940mx. **If** the nvidia card can connect to the laptop's screen directly, **then** there certainly is a solution to your screen tearing issue. However, **if** that is not the case, and the intel gpu is the only gpu with a direct connection to the laptop's screen, **then** you cannot fix your screen tearing issue without huge fps losses. Sources: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/775691/vsync-issue-nvidia-prime-ux32vd-with-gt620-m-/ and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4PflCyiULO4&feature=youtu.be&t=5h00m32s. Someday, this problem will be solved, X.Org Server could be upgraded to handle these types of setups, or maybe a successor to X.Org Server could become popular, but, until then, Windows will allow you to get your money's worth from your laptop.